# Shiny iframe depending on input

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I am trying to build an iframe into my shiny app. The difficulty is with its reactivity, it should load a different image depending on user input.

I tried to build a normal iframe, which works fine:

**ui.R**

```
column(3,
   tags$iframe(src="http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/3014.jpg", height=242, width=242, frameborder=0, seamless="seamless")
)
```

But I'm having trouble with the reactivity. I thought that I just have to paste the correct link into `tags$iframe` but unfortunately that doesn't work. Here are my files:

**server.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$naame <- renderUI({
   members <- data.frame(name=c("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"), nr=c(3014, 2565, 2670))
   selectInput("Member", 
            label=h5("Choose a person"),
            choices=members[,2],
            selected=NULL)
   })


 loadpic <- reactive({ 
    if (!is.null(input$Member)){
     #input$Member can be any number, I use 3014 as an example. bildurl is then
     #http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/3014.jpg
     zahhl <- paste0(members[which(members==input$Member),2])
     bildurl <- paste0("http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/", sep="", zahhl, sep="", ".jpg")

  return(bildurl)}

})

  output$imagehead <- renderText({
    loadpic()
})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Choose your preferred name"), 
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
     fluidRow(#Chooses Name
                    column(6,
                           uiOutput("naame")
                           )),
     mainPanel(fluidRow(column(3,tags$iframe(src=htmlOutput("imagehead"), height=242, width=242))))))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example showing the problem you are having.

Comment: @jdharrison: I updated the code. I hope it's reproducible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `renderUI` and `htmlOutput` to construct the iframe rather the `renderText` there was also numerous errors. A simplified version of the code follows (only your first link gives a picture):

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Choose your preferred name"), 
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      fluidRow(
                        column(6,
                               selectInput("Member", label=h5("Choose a person"),
                                           choices=members[,2])
                        ))),
                    mainPanel(fluidRow(
                      column(3, htmlOutput("imagehead"))
                    )
                    )
                  )
)
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  loadpic <- reactive({ 
    validate(
      need(input$Member, "Member input is null!!")
    )
    zahhl <- members[which(members$nr==input$Member),2]
    paste0("http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/", zahhl, ".jpg")
  })
  output$imagehead <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src=loadpic(), height=242, width=242)
  })
}
)
```

global.R

```
members <- data.frame(name=c("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"), nr=c(3014, 2000, 4358))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that as well, all I get is the url in the application altough it does not load the picture. I suspect it has to do with `src=function`, which does not work?

Comment: Yes your url's are not valid aside from the first one. So http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/3014.jpg works but http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/2000.jpg and http://www.parlament.ch/SiteCollectionImages/profil/225x225/4358.jpg are not valid url's. The code is perfectly correct. Also you will need to view it in a browser. It will not show correctly in rstudio viewer for example.

Comment: If `zahhl` is 3014 it does not work either, it displays only the url. It somehow does not load the picture. In addition I looked up some other and especially valid numbers, I updated my question with them.

Comment: I'm impressed and puzzled at the same time. Your example works for me too. Why wouldn't mine work for me, it still displays only the url instead of loading the pic... I'll get back to you. Thanks in advance.